# How do xmms/modplug tune volume?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I'm using xmms2 0.8 DrO_o + modplug 1.0.0 to have a rich playlist featuring some .ogg/mp3 songs together with old-school sound tracks (.mod, .s3m, .it, .xm). All this runs on ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS, kernel 3.13.0-36 (in a VirtualBox, if you ask)

I have an issue with volume control: as the playlist goes to a new song, the global volume (master and pcm) is boosted up, but as the playlist progress to another ogg/mp3 track, the volume is not restored and the playout is now too loud. xmms2 is configured with `output.plugin = pulse`.

The curious thing is that if I use e.g. alsamixer to move volume by e.g. -5% then +5%, i'm back to a global volume that is much lower than what was playing, as if actual volume setting and mixer volume were no longer in sync.

What coud explain this behaviour? Where should I start investigating ?

Answer (score 0):

I still cannot comment on how xmms2 handles the situation, but switching back to "Analog Output / No Amplifier" in gnome-control-center fixed the issue and there are no longer hard bumps in volume when switching to the next song. The volume controls of e.g. alsamixer also behave as expected.